# Fixed-point FIR Filter Output Size

Tags: filter, fixed-point

I have a 64-tap FIR filter whose output format I am having trouble understanding. The filter has been implemented using (signed) fixed-point math. In {B,F} format, where B is the word length, and F is the fraction length, the filter inputs are {16,0}, and the coefficients are {16,17}. The heart of the filter is as follows:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++) {
    accumulator += coefficients[i] *
        (input[(inputIndex + 64 - i) % 64] +
        input[(inputIndex + 1 + i) % 64]);
}
```

Each iteration of the for loop produces an output whose format is given by:

```
{16,17} * ( {16,0} + {16,0} ) = {16,17} * {17,0}
                              = {33,17}
```

using the rules of fixed-point arithmetic. As there are 32 iterations, it is necessary to add 6 additional bits to the size of the accumulator to prevent overflow. The six bits come from using the (MATLAB) formula:

```
floor(log2(32)) + 1
```

as per [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19880-digital-filters-with-matlab) document. According to my reasoning, this should result in an output of format {39,17}. Why then does MATLAB report the filter output size as {34,17}? Furthermore, if I want the filter output to be the same format as the input, am I correct in thinking that I need to right-shift by (in the {39,17} case) 22 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fine:

```
{16,17} * ( {16,0} + {16,0} ) = {16,17} * {17,0}
                              = {33,17}
```

With 32 iterations, you can generate 5 additional bits (not 6), so it's  `{38,17}`.  MATLAB's output couldn't be right for all possible inputs. Is it considering particular inputs or the general case?

The format of the input `{16,0}` is an integer with no fraction.  So to achieve the same *scale* as the input, you want to merely shift the fraction out, a right shift of 15.  This truncates. Consider adding 0x4000 ~= 1/2 before shifting, a form of rounding.

If you actually want to match the input `{16,0}` exactly, you shift right by 22 (possibly adding 0x200000 first to round). This introduces a scale factor of 1/128 in the transfer function (giving away about -20dB of signal!).  Fine if that's what the problem demands.

Comment: It was merely a typo, now corrected - thank you for pointing it out. With regards to the output, removing the fractional part (15 right-shifts) would leave an integer portion (in the case of your {38,15} sum) 23 bits long. I believe that 5 extra shifts would be needed to ensure the output is the same format as the input.

Comment: Well, if you mean 16 significant bits, then of course we must shift right 38-16=22.  However this introduces a transfer scale factor of 1 / (2^(22 - 15)) = 1/128 with respect to the input.  If that's what you want, great.

Comment: Belay that - I had the coefficient format incorrectly stated. Again, this has been corrected.

Comment: (Navy?)  Okay I think I've adjusted to match.  Thanks.

Comment: I should add that a nice way of testing fixed point code is to write a dp floating point version and have your test frame verify each intermediate fixed point result T{B,F} matches the float T * 2^-F . Then test with maximum inputs to verify no overflows.

Comment: Your point regarding scale is well-taken. It looks as if one of the assumptions I have been (naively) operating under is incorrect - that an output of the same scale as the input would also be the same size as the input - that is, a signed 16-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started studying fixed point DSP implementation myself, but the following two documents have been helpful:

- http://www.digitalsignallabs.com/fp.pdf
- http://www.digitalsignallabs.com/fir.pdf

The first introduces the author's notation for fixed point math, and the second discusses fixed point FIR filters.  In that discussion, he carefully analyzes overflow conditions and the output size of FIR filters.

The most interesting bit is that it's possible to do more than a worst case analysis of overflows, if you consider the values of the coefficients.  If the coefficients are signed and largely cancel each other out (ie. their sum is small), then the number of carry bits generated in the accumulator is smaller, giving a lower upper bound on the output size.